# Iterate through list for number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to search a list to find the value closest to 50%. I track the index of that value, using that to find the median value in another list.  My code isn't working:

```html
def find_median(percent_list, avg_lst):
    closeValueIndex = []
    count = 0 
    med_num = 50 
    for i in percent_list: 
        diff = abs(percent_list - med_num)
        minDiffValue = min(diff)
        if i == minDiffValue: 
            closeValueIndex.append(count)
        count+= 1
    med = avg_lst[count]
    return med
```

Comment: what is the input you are testing against, what is the output you get, and what s the expected output ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

You've confused some of your own concepts, and you're misusing `min`.  Let's look at the code:

```
for i in percent_list: 
    diff = abs(percent_list - med_num)
```

You're doing okay so far; `i` becomes each member of `percent_list`, one at a time.  For each of those, `diff` is the absolute difference from 50.  However, the next line is a logical error:

```
    minDiffValue = min(diff)
```

This won't do anything useful: `diff` is only a single value, so this *must* return that value.

```
    if i = minDiffValue:
```

This is another logical error, but in albegra.  `i` is the list element; `minDiffValue` is its distance from 50.  The only way this will be `True` is for the value 25.  The meaning of this is useless to your program.

Instead, you need to remember the *position* of the least element.  Try the combined iteration

```
for i, value in enumerate(percent_list):
    diff = abs(percent_list - med_num)
    if diff < minDiffValue:
        # Remember the minimum difference and its position
        minDiffValue = diff
        minIndex = i
```

With this, once you finish the loop, you have the minimum discrepancy *and* its position ready to use.

```
return avg_lst[minIndex]
```

There are more "Pythonic" ways to do this, but I think this one is likely best suited to your current level of programming.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. But how come now it tells me that minDiffValue is undefined

Comment: This isn't a packaged solution to your homework; I expect that you know how and when to initialize a value.  For instance, set it to 9999 before you enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enumerate`. It's MADE for tracking indices and elements of a list at the same time.

You can also use a `key` function of `min` to get all this at the same time!

```
def find_median(percent_list, avg_list):
    count, _ = min(enumerate(percent_list), key=lambda ie: abs(ie[1]-50))
    return avg_list[count]
```

This admittedly obfuscate code uses a `lambda` (which is just an anonymous function) to pull out the value from the `(index, value)` pairs you're feeding into it, and selects the minimal element. You could just as easily write:

```
def find_median(percent_list, avg_list):
    min_idx = 0
    min_diff = abs(percent_list[0] - 50)
    for i, val in enumerate(percent_list):
        diff = abs(val - 50)
        if diff < min_diff:
            min_idx, min_diff = i, diff
    return avg_list[min_idx]
```

Or just tersely name your otherwise anonymous function.

```
def diff_from_50(tup):
    _, v = tup  # ignore the first element
    return abs(50 - v)

i, _ = min(enumerate(percent_list), key=diff_from_50)
result = avg_list[i]
```